# Running omnet++ simulations from windows command line

Tags: windows, omnet++

I want to run an OMNeT++ simulation from the Windows Command Line instead of from the command line interface provided in OMNeT itself. Is it possible to run simulations this way? I tried adding the environment variables to the path following the instructions given on omnet++ installation guide as well but it still doesn't work. Any help/hint regarding this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, yes. At a minimum, you have to add the `omnetpp/bin` and `tools/win64/mingw64/bin` to the system path. (with omnet 5.6.2)

Obviously, without you providing what environment variable you set and what was the error, it is not possible to say anything about the actual error.

Comment: I've added all three paths: omnetpp/bin, omnetpp/tools/win64/mingw64/bin and omnetpp/tools/win64/usr/bin. 
 To run the simulation from both mingwenv and windows command line I used the command opp_run -u Cmdenv -c Network -f simulations/omnetpp.ini. The error I keep getting is : The procedure entry pint_z11qt_assert_xPkcS0_S0_i could not be located in the dynamic link library omnetpp\bin\liboppqtenv.dll.  
If I direct the simulation to  project/out/clang-release/src and use the command project.exe -u Cmdenv -c Network -f simulations/omnetpp.ini, then I get the error: "libINET.dll not found"

Comment: Most likely, some  DLL files used by OMNET are also installed on your system (but with an older/incompatible version). Those DLLs are picked up by the system. Welcome to the DLL hell. Make sure that you put all the omnet related PATHs at the beginning of your system path (however if that fixes omnet, it will brake some other apps on the system as they will load the omnet DLLs instead of theor own). This is the reason why omnet uses its own shell where it can control the PATH fully without interfering with other apps on the system.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I have now put all the omnet related PATHs  the beginning of the system path and even still I am getting the same DLL error not just through the windows command line but even by running the opp_run command on the mingwenv.cmd. However, when I set the run configuration to cmdenv from the IDE and run the simulation it works perfectly without any issue